# Inherited attribute/method/static method behavior

Tags: java

Let's setup a simple scenario:

```java
class A {
    String bar = "att A";

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo A");
    }

    public static void sfoo() {
        System.out.println("sfoo A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    String bar = "att B";

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo B");
    }

    public static void sfoo() {
        System.out.println("sfoo B");
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A b = new B();
        b.foo();
        b.sfoo();
        System.out.println(b.bar);
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
foo B
sfoo A
att A
```

I think that `sfoo A` is caused by the static method looking at the type of object, not the object itself — you're free to correct/ammend this.

However, I wonder why `att A` is getting printed. Intuitively I'd say that attributes are stored with the object itself, and would behave similarly to instance methods. Why don't they? Could you explain it in the context of `foo` and `sfoo` (i.e. compare those three cases)?

Comment: Hint about `att A`: [field hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html).... and do `System.out.println(((B)b).bar);` and you'll see

Comment: Word of advice:  Do **not** call `static` methods through an instance variable.  It's a compiler warning at the very least and similar languages (such as C#) treat it as a compiler error, as `static` methods belong to the class rather than the instance/object.  Also, as you've noticed, they don't act like you expect if you're using inheritance.

Comment: @Powerlord Thanks, but don't worry, I have no intention of doing that. Tomorrow is my Java exam, though, and I've heard this is one of the favourite questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a case of field hiding.
class B now has two `bar` members. One in the `A` sub-object and one in the `B` part.
When you access the field on an element whose type is statically defined as `A` you are referring to the field defined in the base class.

You can think of it as equivalent to accessing bar in this way `(((A)b).bar)`

As for an explanation in the context of data vs function instance members:

Accessing instance methods works slightly differently than accessing instance members.
`foo` is a non *final* and thus *virtual* function. The run time chooses the actual method to call by following a pointer from the actual object to a *virtual function table* (if we ignore optimizations), and this pointer is different for objects of type `A` and objects of type `B`, so the actual run time type of object determines which function is actually called.

For accessing variables, the compiler can just issue an instruction to read the address at a known offset from the beginning of the object. This offset is strictly determined by the compile time type of the object, so the declared type of the object will determine which bar member is read.

BTW You are correct that in accessing the static function the compiler ignores the object, and calls the function statically using the class type.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. From your answer it seems that it's a rather arbitrary choice whether `B.bar` or `A.bar` will be returned — we know both that the declared type is `A` and the real type is `B` by compile time and can choose one of the `bar`s accordingly. Is there a specific reason why it is the way it is?

Comment: The real type is not known at compile time. Imagine the following situation: `if userInput.equals("Yes") b = new A(); else b = new B();` That's why instance functions use the v-table mechanism at run-time to get to the correct code. By the language design this mechanism is not used with data members.